# could not connect to cassandra using the latest cql driver and default settings?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I am using the latest version of cassandra 3.0.2 and the latest version of datastax cassandra core java driver which is 3.0.0. The settings in cassandra.yaml remains unchanged. I have not changed that file. so whatever the default settings are they remain the same. I keep hearing that rpc_address should be 0.0.0.0 but by default it is localhost and the broadcast_rpc_address by default is commmented out however its value is 1.2.3.4 (again by default it is commented out). I have not changed any of the default settings so the cassandra.yaml file remains unchanged. I also don't understand why we need to set rpc_address and all that after all I hear that latest version of cassandra had moved away from rpc?!

Here is the snippet of the code

```
Cluster cassandra = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost").withPort(9042).build();
ListenableFuture<Session> session = cassandra.connectAsync("demo1");
......
```

Here is the error that I get when I turn on the DEBUG FLAG

```
    com.datastax.driver.NEW_NODE_DELAY_SECONDS is undefined, using default value 1
com.datastax.driver.NON_BLOCKING_EXECUTOR_SIZE is undefined, using default value 8
com.datastax.driver.NOTIF_LOCK_TIMEOUT_SECONDS is undefined, using default value 60
Starting new cluster with contact points [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
com.datastax.driver.FORCE_NIO is undefined, using default value false
Did not find Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, defaulting to NIO.
[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] preparing to open 1 new connections, total = 1
com.datastax.driver.DISABLE_COALESCING is undefined, using default value false
Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] Connection established, initializing transport
[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] Transport initialized, connection ready
[Control connection] Refreshing node list and token map
You listed localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042 in your contact points, but it wasn't found in the control host's system.peers at startup
[Control connection] Refreshing schema
[Control connection] Refreshing node list and token map
[Control connection] established to localhost/127.0.0.1:9042
Using data-center name 'datacenter1' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct datacenter name with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy constructor)
New Cassandra host localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 added
[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] preparing to open 1 new connections, total = 2
Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-2, inFlight=0, closed=false] Connection established, initializing transport
[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-2, inFlight=0, closed=false] Transport initialized, connection ready
Created connection pool to host localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (1 connections needed, 1 successfully opened)
Added connection pool for localhost/127.0.0.1:9042
Preparing query SELECT "hash" AS col1,"body" AS col2 FROM demo1.ents WHERE "hash"=?;
[1795897147-1] Doing retry 1 for query com.datastax.driver.core.Statement$1@19be093f at consistency null
[1795897147-1] Error querying localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 : com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [localhost/127.0.0.1] Timed out waiting for server response
error message -> All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [localhost/127.0.0.1] Timed out waiting for server response))
error cause -> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [localhost/127.0.0.1] Timed out waiting for server response))
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [localhost/127.0.0.1] Timed out waiting for server response))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:84)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:98)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.getPreparedQuery(Mapper.java:118)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.getPreparedQuery(Mapper.java:129)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.getQuery(Mapper.java:333)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.getQuery(Mapper.java:325)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.getAsync(Mapper.java:388)
```

Here is where the exeption happens in cassandra driver

```
    stmt = session().prepare(queryString); //Mapper.java

    public PreparedStatement prepare(String query) { //AbstractSession.java
    try {
        return Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(prepareAsync(query));
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        throw DriverThrowables.propagateCause(e);
    }
}
```